# How do I insert an item repeatedly between every two elements of an array?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I have this code:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3]
let sep = 0
```

I want to insert `sep` between every two elements of `items` to get a result similar to this:

```
newItems = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

Is there a concise way to do this through functional programming in Swift? Something similar to `String.join()`, but for arrays.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

(*Note:* The answer has been updated for Swift 3 and later with the help of [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324431/1187415) and [ober's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41766453/1187415)).

This does the trick:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3]
let sep = 0

let newItems = Array(items.map { [$0] }.joined(separator: [sep]))
print(newItems) // [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

`items.map { [ $0 ] }` creates an array of single-element arrays, and `joined(separator: [sep])` then interposes the separator and concatenates
the elements. The result is a `JoinedSequence` from which we can create an `Array`.

As it turns out (benchmarks below) it is quite expensive to create many temporary arrays. This can be avoided by using “single-element collections”:

```
let newItems = Array(items.map(CollectionOfOne.init).joined(separator: CollectionOfOne(sep)))
```

Another possible solution is

```
let newItems = (0 ..< 2 * items.count - 1).map { $0 % 2 == 0 ? items[$0/2] : sep }
```

which maps even indices to the corresponding element of `items`,
and odd indices to the separator. This turns out to be the fastest solution for large arrays.

*Benchmark:* With `items` containing 1,000,000 elements, compiled in Release mode on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro, I measured the following approximate execution times:

- First method (`map` + `joined` with arrays): 0.28 seconds.
- Second method (`map` + `joined` with `CollectionOfOne`): 0.035 seconds.
- Third method (using only `map`): 0.015 seconds.

Comment: I don't know how I missed `Array.join`. Thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use a reference type as a separator, changing it will change all the instances inserted into the array!

Comment: @martin How can I insert repeatedly after 5th index ?

Comment: Awesome solution

Comment: WHAT a SMART solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

converted to swift 5

```
extension Array {

  func insert(separator: Element) -> [Element] {
    (0 ..< 2 * count - 1).map { $0 % 2 == 0 ? self[$0/2] : separator }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is the original answer converted to Swift 3/4

```
let items = [1, 2, 3]
let sep = 0

let newItems = Array(items.map { [$0] }.joined(separator: [sep]))

print(newItems) // [1, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

Comment: This answer not good, because you create a new array for each separator

Comment: @ober I'm not sure what you're saying, that's just how the function works.  You have to match the type of the separator with the type that you're joining.

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690077-joined

Comment: I think what he is saying is that each time the joined iterator "inserts" an element, internally, it creates a new array. As the OP mentioned, this may not be the most efficient use of memory. This mostly applies if you're dealing with massively sized lists. If not, using joined should be efficient enough. If you expect your lists to scale to an unknown level, you should probably look to implement a slightly more efficient method as the OP mentions.